# How to define a function about forward price?

Tags: python, finance

I have to define a function, `forward_price` which takes three parameters:

```
spot: float
interest_rate: float
time: float
```

This function should compute and return the forward price, rounded at 2 decimals, of an asset in a forward contract using this classical formula:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VujSB.png)

I tried this :

```
from math import e
interest_rate = 1.03 #risk free-rate is 3%
spot_price = 40 
time = 30/360 #there is 30 days remaining
forward_price = spot_price * e ** interest_rate * time 
print(forward_price)
```

the result is `9.336886115663596` while the true result should be 40.10

Does someone know how to get this result and round it?

Comment: try putting parenthesis around interest_rate * time. I think as you have it written, the equation is being read as spot_price * (e^interest_rate) * time

Comment: Thank you. The expected result is 40.10. When time = 1 the result is 112, which is a really bad result. I don't know why

Comment: Why is 112 bad? Calculator tells me that 40 * e^(1.03 + 1) = 112.04. The forward price for 1 year period should be more? What is the expected value for 1 year.

Comment: For 1 year expected value is 41.22. I reached it with this code :

From math import e
interest_rate = 0.03
spot_price = 40
time = 1
rt = time * interest_rate

print(rt)
forward_price = spot_price * e ** rt

print(forward_price)

I dont know why it doesnt work with the previous code, i am a very new python user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to come from adding 1 to the interest rate. If you leave the `interest_rate` as `0.03` and add parentheses around the exponent, you get the expected value.

```
from math import e
interest_rate = 0.03 #risk free-rate is 3%
spot_price = 40 
time = 30/360 #there is 30 days remaining
forward_price = spot_price * e ** (interest_rate * time) 
print(forward_price)
```

Comment: No problem. If the answer was helpful, I would appreciate it if you marked it as accepted. @AntoineDaSilva

Comment: for sure yes !!